# Why cmyk colors are displayed wrong on screen?

Tags: color, pdf, plain-tex

If we compile this with `pdftex` and open in evince 3.18.2-1 (and other viewers), the color is violet, instead of [blue](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/cmyk-to-rgb.htm):

```
\pdfliteral{1 1 0 0 k}
\vrule height 5cm width 5cm
\bye
```

Please somebody share your experience how you use colors in pdftex and which viewer you use to display them on screen correctly (on linux).

I read a lot of forums, but i can't understand why CMYK colors are
displayed incorrectly on screen. I found this bug report:
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14526
Is it relevant here? Is it a bug in poppler library?

Some explanation of this mess would be much appreciated.

*NOTE* If we use Grey color space, the colors are displayed correctly. But let's suppose that we want to use CMYK. How do we do it properly in plain tex?

**UPDATE**

There is very enlightening information:

---

The problem is with different color spaces based on different physical principles of visualization. In printed-oriented color space (CMYK), e.g., "0 0 0 1 k" means: use zero cyan, zero magenta, zero yellow but full black ink.

The Gay color space is derived from RGB (but more simple) and it is based on the light intensity. "0 g" means: use zero light on your monitor. "1 g" means: use full light, but what does it mean? What is white? The light intensity when one is looking to a white paper and perceives the reflected light? But how strong is the light source during this experiment? Is here the dusk or we are at direct sunlight? How much the paper reflects the light? Is it good paper or recycled paper? All these light conditions cannot be included to the calculation when we say "0 0 0 0 k" which means "white like used paper". What light intensity chooses the visualizer which uses the monitor in this situation? It is absolutely impossible to know this. So the "printing" color space is unconvertable to "light" color space. But we need to do some estimations, when we need to do the conversion of color spaces.

These estimations are incorporated to the ICC profiles. May be the ICC profile used by evince supposes that the full black ink will reflect a slight part of the light back to the user eye. But this is only an *estimation* because the ICC profile is unable to know the quality of used ink (and the quality of used paper too). Maybe it represents the fact that printing technology (using CMYK) is unable to print absolutely black color because the black ink cannot be absolutely black(?).

Such estimations are bad from physical principle, so best solution is simply use "no light" for "0 0 0 1 k". But the developers of evince have different opinion. Evince developers decided, that the black color in CMYK colorspace must be repesented differently than black color in Grey and RGB space.

---

So, the question becomes this: how to change [ICC profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile) for evince?

**ANSWER**

If in CMYK you need to make at least black color look really black on monitor (because greyish text is somewhat harder to read), use the following patch for poppler pdf rendering library:

```
--- poppler-0.44.0.orig/poppler/GfxState.cc
+++ poppler-0.44.0/poppler/GfxState.cc
@@ -1453,6 +1453,11 @@
   rgb->r = clip01(dblToCol(r));
   rgb->g = clip01(dblToCol(g));
   rgb->b = clip01(dblToCol(b));
+  if ((color->c[0] == 0) && (color->c[1] == 0) && (color->c[2] == 0) && (color->c[3] == 65536)) {
+    rgb->r = 0;
+    rgb->g = 0;
+    rgb->b = 0;
+  }
 }

 static inline void GfxDeviceCMYKColorSpacegetRGBLineHelper(Guchar *&in, double &r, double &g, double &b)
```

I posted the bug report [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97103).

Comment: given that the screen is basically an rgb device why not use `rg` rather than `k` conversion between colour models is always a tricky thing, Do you mean grey in your note, you'd get no colour then at all, presumably, just  greyscale?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, maybe it is not Grey, I don't know exactly... I just need to use CMYK colors and get the display right. Is it the problem with pdf viewer or with `pdftex`? Does somewhere exist a description of what `rg` and `k` exactly mean?

Comment: rgb is red green blue so `0 0 1 rg` is blue `k` is cmyk so `1 1 0 0 k` is cyan and magenta mixed (no yellow or black) which is sort of mathematically the same thing but try mixing paint pots to get the same colour...

Comment: converting between cmyk and rgb in a real device is _complicated_ see http://www.helios.de/support/manuals/isUB64-e/colors.html

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then we need to use separate scheme for printer and separate for screen? Is there a rigorous mathematical theorem which shows a contradiction if we encode the same color in two different schemes?

Comment: side note: this is in no-way a plain tex issue. Same happens in latex. But you can use `[rgb]` option to `xcolor` to get all your document color specifications be converted to `rgb` model before getting written to `pdf`, thus giving at least the result that a naive `cmyk` spec for "blue" will give the same thing as a "blue" specified using `rgb` color model.

Comment: @jfbu: If xcolor can convert from cmyk to rgb, why pdf renderer can't? What is the "native" color scheme for pdf? Is it converted to rgb when rendered on screen and to cmyk when sent to printer? What for so many color schemes? How are they supposed to fit together? Does there exist any standard somewhere?

Comment: I would have to do some research before answering your questions... for example I need to delete my earlier comments about what I said of xcolor's doc of `rgb<->cmyk`. You find this in 6.3.2 where device-dependence is strongly emphasized, with mention of the `UCR_c`, `UCR_m`, `UCR_y` and `BG` functions. I searched `target device` in the do to see if one could pass it as option, but found nothing.

Comment: As I found these links somewhat illuminating, I am repeating them here: http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/color-space-conversion.htm, http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/color-spaces.htm, but for your question something PDF specific would be required.

Comment: Perhaps 8.6 Colour Spaces in [PDF spec](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) will help ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the relation between color profiles and PDF viewers

Comment: @egreg: at first I though that it was something wrong with pdftex, but now I understand the problem. Could you please recommend an appropriate place to ask such question?